# Get bitmap of a custom view

Tags: android

I've been trying to build a customView that would act like a Paint type of View so the user could sign his name and than to save that as a .PNG and export it to the sdcar. I have looked over the internet for solutions and found out that there's 2 ways of doing it.

1. Creating a bitmap of the size of the view adding it to a Canvas and than drawing the view to the canvas.

and

2. setting the drawingCache to true for the view and building it/getting it as a Bitmap and writing that to the sdcard.

   Both solutions failed for the custom view i have, but if I get the root view of my custom view it works(myView.getRootView()) ...
   This is the code to my custom view.

   ```
   public class SignatureView extends View{
   private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
   private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
   private Paint paint = new Paint();
   private Path path = new Path();

   private float lastTouchX;
   private float lastTouchY;
   private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

   public SignatureView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet) {
     super(context,attributeSet);

     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
     paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
   }

   public void clear() {
     path.reset();

     // Repaints the entire view.
     invalidate();
   }

   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      float eventX = event.getX();
      float eventY = event.getY();

      switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
           lastTouchX = eventX;
           lastTouchY = eventY;
           // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
           return true;

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           // Start tracking the dirty region.
           resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

           // When the hardware tracks events faster than they are delivered, the
           // event will contain a history of those skipped points.
           int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
           for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
               float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
               float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
               expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
               path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
           }

           // After replaying history, connect the line to the touch point.
           path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
           break;

       default:
           //debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
           return false;
   }

   // Include half the stroke width to avoid clipping.
       invalidate(
           (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
           (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
           (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
           (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

       lastTouchX = eventX;
       lastTouchY = eventY;

       return true;
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
     if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
       dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
         } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
       dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
                 }
   if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
       dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
       } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
       dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
              }
     }

   private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

     // The lastTouchX and lastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN
     // motion event occurred.
     dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
     dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
     dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
     dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
   }
   ```

And this is the code to the MainActivity that tries to get the bitmap of the signatureView and export it to sdcard.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

SignatureView sigView;
RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //sigView = new SignatureView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sigView = (SignatureView) findViewById(R.id.SigView);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_clear){
        //drawView.clearAll();
        sigView.clear();
    }
    if(id==R.id.action_save){
        saveBitmap();
        PdfCreator.getInstance().createTestPDF();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/* ToBeFixed!!!
 Tried both ways(Adding a bitmap to a Canvas and drawing the View to the Canvas
  aswell as Building the drawing cache and getting that as a bitmap... None work
  with the custom view(SignatureView) or it's parrent(RelativeLayout). But the View
  fetched from view.getRootView() works.... Help
  */
public void saveBitmap(){
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v = sigView; 
    // View v = sigView.getRootView() <-- This Works :| But I need it to work for the sigView
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.buildDrawingCache(true);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    //Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    //bitmap = Util.getResizedBitmap(bitmap,150,300);
    //v.draw(c);

    // ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try{
        f.delete();
        Log.d("SignatureView23", "createNewFile =" + f.createNewFile());
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        // fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, fo);
        fo.close();}
    catch(Exception e){}
    //layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}}
```

Thank you in advance, and sorry if the first part of SignatureView class is not formatted properly...

Comment: Could you add in a bit of clarity in your question?  It sounds as though you have it in a working condition.  Do you just want an improvement and/or and explanation as to why it is working in this manner?

Comment: It works only if I get the root view of my custom view. It does not work with my custom view(SignatureView). Saving the rootView of my customView to a Bitmap will render me a Screenshot of the screen, since the rootView is top most view and contains all the displayed elements. I would like to get it working with my custom view(SignatureView) so I can only render that without the titlebar and other elements in the exported picture. I don't understand why the System sees my customView(SignatureView) empty even thou it is taking the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to add

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

in my onDraw of the SignatureView and also

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
       if (mBitmap == null) {
       Log.i("", "onSizeChanged BITMAP NULL");
       mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       }

       if (mCanvas == null) {
       mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
       }
    }
```

I guess the custom view needs a Bitmap... Can't really explain it more... Not even to myself. I'm just glad it works now :). I hope this helps someone else as well.